# Applescript and shell

Tags: shell, applescript

I need to do a command « minimize patch » in MaxMSP. I searched but couldn't find it. I think it’s possible to command « minimize patch » with object shell. Can you help with script message for shell?

Answer (score 0):

----------begin_max5_patcher----------
    978.3oc2XkzabBCE97L+JPjJkKjTLqCsmxkdqUppWpTUTjYvg3TvLBLISaT9
    uWu.yRlwfCCYZRt.lGOdKeuE+LOLchYbwRTkowmL9kwjIOLcxDAINgIMOOwL
    GtbdFrRvlIAceQ7slVxWQQKoBxU2fxxZot.RmeCljdUIZNUJbfm641VFt91x
     a7qNr0FW17M3DgbXx9LPTqfttfPIvbj3UWThgqTQQMMCQo+YARJeSSKCyXHI
    0bkD4ebE9uBF.NLEJISpywD12JbGvZhRIJn5vI93zo7KVZhK4npJXJZGfonB
    VMuDufZbFx3TJCkLXe2GY1.NmYbFzxZzo8CbNQQ7afn.wsYJPtvgfbqjTb57
    hrhxFEyUj8491LcB3q35cC0pC75rW3EL.3cdQdNhP2AdawwtPPY1lqvgBC5L
    yKne7SgeecYZLmj8yIQyd.HghBvrBXBOGrCfvyUDD8E.QfSm.g+AkHM7Rugj
    aPKRSyP863QtstbGNtmR2CyR+V8IKfkLPghJuBQfwYBddgcSEAdVYQcLrre2
    G3Jx88iN2uC+2c.AdNxXsuaiPBgWC0J3csp6juwk+J+lwBC5ML+Lm5I+jeEF
    yj.ewEsK9Jbo417LOqnBgon7mPGQRjTLtbD2F355rL19.HDw3CfNhUN.Q0IH
    T1sJpyt8Nu3EoiWCbU.icWfgmb2NYqaWGdhqRv.7N.LzIyPKvv9MDXnnuFqq
    NJIE0OhDI1d22qq15CYhRwzj+mmpT0XOeg0N4Gh1I8iO5L3yrW+y8npl4dQi
    7NfAomKyR7B6pgZ36fplavUBL.U1Kj33HmDLpqLifAdVrQohQ0d+a4ks6d+8
    Ce2aUka8lhYutPyysK3z+0egVbMkVnQek.u9Gmd8zjadzx1yRtmSUFmgI+dK
    Vc7sil04IQ2em68epVUxaS6eu3JWIXBZKQEBbCcBrTrZKAdfU68FSZ9MA5DS
    b1aLoui6uafYMqqfzCJvDwQNeKEqdaGdjMb0I5.5J5X+LCL1u9BJ6Zb5EJDr
    XxE2S9ckBzlSe63SUQc47VWrIs2XshRPUTLARwrv1Zd3++rMX5FbRBhr4Q6S
    vU7S6mnt2ptlySTkB6I53YO95XOdGO6wSG6w83YO5j+Dzi4jiSVTfIzlTXGV
    S.w+hwieal+pGVqlwy9A5fmNOSGvWXyfl+ojzcDO8R3A1igGLd1SjNli8Q0b
    .8YNfil43pA5b75tENBEuiXlrFVyP2IRtOIbwh6PkUMhTXHrIVtUtMbfk3QL
    Q9nX2ZyRzc3V9kL.KYSwPYivTWJOkxxYAlS454wo+C.PxjFy
    -----------end_max5_patcher-----------